# Update a column after joining two tables with where clause

Tags: database, sqlite

I have two tables

threads table

```
_id   recipient_id    type
 1     1
 2     1
 3     2
```

and addresses table

```
_id    address
1      HELLO
2      BYE
```

recipient_id is mapped to addresses table's _id

I need to update `type` to a specific value if address is HELLO. How do i do it? I have already tried

```
UPDATE   threads SET threads.type = 106 FROM threads  
   INNER JOIN 
   addresses  ON addresses._id = threads.recipient_ids
    AND
   addresses.address LIKE '%HELLO%';
```

But i am getting an error `near ".": syntax error` . 
What is the correct syntax to update a column?

Comment: Does SQLite support `UPDATE FROM`? https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html

Comment: Thanks for the info. i did not know that. So how can i do it without UPDATE FROM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`IN`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) operator:

```
sqlite> .dump
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE threads (_id integer primary key, recipient_id integer, type text);
INSERT INTO "threads" VALUES(1,1,NULL);
INSERT INTO "threads" VALUES(2,1,NULL);
INSERT INTO "threads" VALUES(3,2,NULL);
CREATE TABLE addresses (_id integer primary key, address text);
INSERT INTO "addresses" VALUES(1,'HELLO');
INSERT INTO "addresses" VALUES(2,'BYE');
COMMIT;
sqlite> update threads set type = 106 where _id in
   ...> (select t._id from threads t, addresses  a
   ...>  where t.recipient_id = a._id and a.address like '%HELLO%');
sqlite> .dump
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE threads (_id integer primary key, recipient_id integer, type text);
INSERT INTO "threads" VALUES(1,1,'106');
INSERT INTO "threads" VALUES(2,1,'106');
INSERT INTO "threads" VALUES(3,2,NULL);
CREATE TABLE addresses (_id integer primary key, address text);
INSERT INTO "addresses" VALUES(1,'HELLO');
INSERT INTO "addresses" VALUES(2,'BYE');
COMMIT;
```